# Impose Curfew Over

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

According to most dictionaries, the verb "*impose*" should be used with the proposition "*on*" like this:

> The mayor imposed a curfew on the city.

But a google search suggests that preposition "*over*" could be used in place of "*on*", like [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/08/26/international/middleeast/26CND-MIDE.html):

> In the northern West Bank today, Israel ***imposed a curfew over*** the city of Jenin as troops searched for a suspected suicide bomber, the Israeli army said.

What do native speakers think about "*over*"?

Comment: Dictionaries can't be expected to list *every* possible preposition that might be validly used with any given verb - they just give *typical* usages. So given [Google Books only claims about 608 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+curfew+over%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for *a curfew **over*** (as opposed to [About 40,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+curfew+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for *a curfew **on***), you won't necessarily expect to find an example in a dictionary. But I'm sure no native speaker loses sleep over your cited usage.

Comment: ...and let's not forget [*a curfew **across***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+curfew+across%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 1):

*X over Y* can be used if X is covering Y completely, or if you could otherwise use the verb *cover* to express how X and Y relate to each other physically.

*Cover* can mean *to set (a blanket, lid, hat, or something similar) on top of*, or it can mean *to touch/do something to all parts of something*.

> We covered all chapters in the book.
>
> We have gone over all chapters in the book.

So you can think of *curfew over a city* as meaning the curfew is intended to reach/touch/affect the entirety of the city.  You could say *Tonight's curfew covers the entire city* and make sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curfew%20on%2Ccurfew%20over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurfew%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurfew%20over%3B%2Cc0) shows 'curfew on' is used far more often. That said, 'curfew over' is not wrong.